# Why setTimeout() doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is my first Java Script app.
I am writing a music application, and one of its parts must play the notes that are stored in a two-dimensional array in turn. I use `setTimeout()` for this with a periodically increasing delay so that the notes are played sequentially.
the problem is that `setTimeout()` causes a function `play(...)` without delay and all notes sound simultaneously
UPD: I changed my code as advised in the comments, replaced the fore..in with foreach, the problem remained the same

```
 function playAll() {
        var j = 0;
        noteArr.forEach(function (item,i,arr) {
            var delay = 500 * j;
            j++;
            item.forEach(function(item,i,arr){
                setTimeout(play(item), delay);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: setTimeout(() => { play(noteArr[key][key2]); }, delay); in ES6 way or setTimeout(function(){ play(noteArr[key][key2]); }, delay) will do the hack.

Comment: @Hyunnique that won't work. By the time those run, `key` and `key2` will be at their final values. OP would do better using `forEach` instead of `for..in`

Comment: @Phil, can you open my question? Solution by link does not suit me

Comment: I guarantee the answer to your question can be found in the linked duplicate

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry, it really helped